# Stepper on tableview cell (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistepper

I put stepper both outlets and action into tableview cell and using protocol delegate to connect it to tableview. When i tapped stepper in first row, stepper value appear normaly in first row but its also appear in some random row. how to fix this?

**TableViewCell**

```
protocol ReviewCellDelegate{
    func stepperButton(sender: ReviewTableViewCell)
}

class ReviewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   @IBOutlet weak var countStepper: UIStepper!
   @IBOutlet weak var stepperLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@IBAction func stepperButtonTapped(sender: UIStepper) {
    if delegate != nil {
        delegate?.stepperButton(self)
        stepperLabel.text = "x \(Int(countStepper.value))"

    }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "reviewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ReviewTableViewCell


    var imageView: UIImageView?
    let photoG = self.photos[indexPath.row]
    imageView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as? UIImageView
    //let layout = cell.goodiesImage
    let tag = indexPath.row // +1
    cell.tag = tag
    photoG.fetchImageWithSize(CGSize(width: 1000, height: 1000), completeBlock: { image, info in
        if cell.tag == tag {
            imageView?.image = image
            cell.goodiesImage.image = image
        }
    })

func stepperButton(sender: ReviewTableViewCell) {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender){
        print(indexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: The cells returned from dequeue **Reusable** CellWithIdentifier are reused when user scrolls the table view, you need to update each view accordingly.

Comment: hi @A-Live how to update it?

Comment: anyway i just updated my code in here bcs i forgot to copy it, where should i put this code "stepperLabel.text = "x \(Int(countStepper.value))" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @A-Live, your component is being reused and so need to be updated.

So in your view controller:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "reviewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ReviewTableViewCell


    var imageView: UIImageView?
    let photoG = self.photos[indexPath.row]
    imageView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as? UIImageView
    //let layout = cell.goodiesImage
    let tag = indexPath.row // +1
    cell.tag = tag
    photoG.fetchImageWithSize(CGSize(width: 1000, height: 1000), completeBlock: { image, info in
    if cell.tag == tag {
        imageView?.image = image
        cell.goodiesImage.image = image
    }
})
    cell.countStepper.value = XXX[indexPath.row].value; //Here you update your view
    cell.stepperLabel.text = "x \(Int(cell.countStepper.value))" //And here
```

And

```
func stepperButton(sender: ReviewTableViewCell) {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender){
        print(indexPath)
        XXX[sender.tag].value = sender.counterStepper.value //Here you save your updated value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reset the value of stepper while loading your cell. you can reset the cell property values in cell's `prepareForReuse` method. add the following method in your `ReviewTableViewCell` class.

```
 override func prepareForReuse() 
 {
   super.prepareForReuse()

   countStepper.value = 0.0 
 }
```

Comment: hi @raki its still transfering a value to another cell

Answer (score 2):

In tableViewCell VC:

1 - add these field

```
var cellDelegate: cellProtocol?
var index: IndexPath?
```

2 - then add this in the delegate:

```
func onStepperClick(index: Int, sender: UIStepper)
```

3 - when you have dragged your stepper over as an action use this:

```
@IBAction func cellStepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    cellDelegate?.onStepperClick(index: (index?.row)!, sender: sender)
    sender.maximumValue = 1  //for incrementing
    sender.minimumValue = -1 //for decrementing
    //this will make sense later
}
```

In ViewController

1 - add these to the tableView function that has the cellAtRow variable.

```
cell.cellDelegate = self
cell.index = indexPath
```

2 - Use this instead of your stepperButton function

```
func onStepperClick(index: Int, sender: UIStepper) {
    print(index)

    if sender.value == 1.0{
        //positive side of stepper was pressed
    }else if sender.value == -1.0{
        //negative side of stepper was pressed
    }

    sender.value = 0  //resetting to zero so sender.value produce different values on plus and minus

}
```

Hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: 
1.MY Cell class is just normal..All changes are in viewcontroller class
2.I have taken stepper and over it added ibAddButton with same constraint as ibStepper

```
class cell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var ibAddButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ibStepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet weak var ibCount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ibLbl: UILabel!
}
```

1.define empty int array `[Int]()`

var countArray = `[Int]()`

2.append countArray with all zeros with the number of data u want to populate in tableview

```
 for arr in self.responseArray{
        self.countArray.append(0)
   }
```

3.in cell for row at

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:
 IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! cell
         let dict = responseArray[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary ?? NSDictionary()
         cell.ibLbl.text = dict["name"] as? String ?? String()
         if countArray[indexPath.row] == 0{
             cell.ibAddButton.tag = indexPath.row
             cell.ibStepper.isHidden = true
             cell.ibAddButton.isHidden = false
             cell.ibCount.isHidden = true
             cell.ibAddButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
         }else{
             cell.ibAddButton.isHidden = true
             cell.ibStepper.isHidden = false
             cell.ibStepper.tag = indexPath.row
             cell.ibCount.isHidden = false
             cell.ibCount.text = "\(countArray[indexPath.row])"
             cell.ibStepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stepperValueChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)}
    return cell
     }
```

4.objc functions

```
 @objc func stepperValueChanged(sender : UIStepper){
     if sender.stepValue != 0{
         countArray[sender.tag] = Int(sender.value)
     }
     ibTableView.reloadData()
 }
 @objc func addPressed(sender : UIButton){

     countArray[sender.tag] = 1//countArray[sender.tag] + 1
     ibTableView.reloadData()
 }
```